# How to add space in JSON while mapping to 2 field in Apex class?

Tags: apex, json, callout, apexrest

I'm trying to map 2 fields Firstname and LastName to a Json Name field, when I call the API its displaying FirstNameLastName, how do i add space between these 2 fields?

```
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeObjectField('name', c.Patient_First_Name__c + c.Patient_Last_Name__c);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to simply add a space:

```
gen.writeObjectField('name', c.Patient_First_Name__c + ' ' + c.Patient_Last_Name__c);
```

Comment: Tried that but it still shows name as one string field as FirstNameLastName, is this issue with the Name field in External System? May be its processing it as one string word?

Comment: Never mind, I tried it again this time it worked!  Thanks very much